# "App Web is not deployed for this app's request url" when trying to use SharePoint 2013's REST server and CSOM

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-apps

to get SharePoint List dataI am having an issue accessing the REST server via the CSOM. I have tried this with both the CSOM and just using jQuery. Code examples and the associated errors below. Can anyone direct me to a working example or tell me what I am doing wrong?

This code is part of a SharePoint Hosted App and the list is just a list in the root web. The user has permission to access the list and the app.

**CSOM Example:** 
***Yields:*** 
Fail! : App Web is not deployed for this app's request url http://mySharePointRootWebURL.local.

```
var data = new SP.RequestExecutor("http://mySharePointRootWebURL.local/");
data.executeAsync({
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    url: "http://mySharePointRootWebURL.local/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'MyLstName\')/items",
    success: function (data) { console.log('success!'); },
    error: function (p1,p2,errorMessage) { console.log('Fail! :' + errorMessage); }
    });
```

I can see that this example is not hitting the root web at all (from the app / app web).

---

**jQuery Example**
***Yields:*** 
Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://mySharePointRootWebURL.local/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'MyLstName\')/items&…Query19104068602353800088_1379462071044&alt=json-in-script&_=1379462071045". jquery.js:9597
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < items:1
fail! : Error: jQuery19104068602353800088_1379462071044 was not called

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "http://mySharePointRootWebURL.local/_api/web/lists/getbytitle(\'MyListName\')/items",
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function(xhr){
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json;odata=verbose'); },
    headers: {"Accept":"application/json;odata=verbose"},
    success: function(data){ console.log("success"); },
    error: function errHandler(p1,p2,errMessage){ console.log("fail! : " + errMessage); },
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {
        alt: 'json-in-script'
    },
});
```

This is working as far as accessing the REST server and returning data, the problem is that the headers are not being added at all (verified in Fiddler). Without the headers the data comes back in XML. If that's how it has to be I will work with it, I guess, but I'd prefer to get JSON.

Comment: **$.ajax() issue is solved:**
A friend turned me onto http://enable-cors.org/ and this took care of it. Haven't noticed any fallout from the change. I did the IIS 7 web.config change. Also in that example you can remove the beforeSend, dataType, crossDomain, and data options completely.

The CSOM+Cross Domain Library issue remains outstanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't look right. Here's code that wors with the cross-domain library

```
   var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

    executor.executeAsync(
    {
        url:
        appweburl +
        "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getByTitle('Contacts')/items" +
                        "?@target='" + hostweburl + "'" +
                        "&$select=Id,FirstName,Title,WorkPhone,Email" +
                        "&$orderby=Title,FirstName",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
        success: successHandler,
        error: errorHandler
    })
```

Comment: That worked great! I just want to note that the appweburl is formatted as http://[appPrefix]-[generatedId].appDomain/AppName/, and is not simply http://appdomain/. This was causing a problem as I had hardcoded it and it took a while to figure out what I needed in there. I now have some js to grab the SPAppWebUrl and SPHostUrl from the querystring. Thank you, Scot!

Comment: What if you aren't creating an appweb and are working solely from the host web inside the Provider hosted app?